# Nonaligned lines...is it normal?

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir

I have been editing a book, and I have stumbled upon this...

[image]

The lines...from odd and even pages are not aligned...My questions is..Is it normal? I mean...I could define a paragraph spacing between lines equals 0, so that would make the lines aligned...But in my opinion that is kind of hacking.

My MWE and what I think maybe influences it.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,showtrims,a5paper]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Define identação em todo primeiro parágrafo
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
\usepackage{leading} %Define espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstocksize{21cm}{14cm} %Define tamanho do livro
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{2cm}{*} %Define margem vertical maior TOP/BOT
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{*} %Define margem horizontal maior
\setheadfoot{1.5cm}{1cm} %Distancia do texto pro número da página
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{0.5}
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem horizontal maior

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} 
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{} %remove a string "Capítulo"
    \pagenumbering{gobble} %oculta numeração de página
    \sloppy %corrige palavras excedendo margens
    \leading{16pt} %orientação de leading
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show the compilable code that generates this?

Comment: There you go @ChristianHupfer

Comment: I don't see why this poses a problem, there are bunch of reasons why this could be desired to make the page look evenly filled a.s.o. i don't think (but that might just be me), that it helps the aestetics if lines are perfectly aligned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is dependent on the length within `\parskip`. If it has some glue, it may stretch to better-fit the page. In your case, I see

```
> 0.0pt plus 1.0pt
> l.22 \showthe\parskip
```

implying that your `\parskip` could be anything from 0pt to 1pt, which leads to what you see as a mis-alignment within the baselines.

Is this normal? Sure. It allows for some flexibility with the page construction. Otherwise, non-baseline-constructions (like figures) could cause issues on the page.

Can it be changed? Yes. Simply issuing `\setlength{\parskip}{1\parskip}` removes the glue. Sometimes people would issue `\raggedbottom` to avoid underfilled pages if there is no glue available to stretch content.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Do you mean it has this mis-alignment so it can fit the whole page correctly? 
I believe it is this, because I have checked the pages and that is what happens...The mis-alignment occurs mid-page but in the finishing line it is the same.

Comment: @Adriano: Correct.

Answer (score 8):

To align lines on different pages (or columns) you need to typeset "on a grid". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_%28graphic_design%29). That's rather difficult in LaTeX. There are a lot of irregular spaces and line heights which don't fit on a grid, e.g. sectioning commands, display math, lists.

But in your case where only normal text is on the page you are getting the misaligned lines because your page layout is wrong: With \leading{16pt} you are changing the line spacing and the textheight is no longer a multiple of the leading and so LaTeX uses the stretchable `\parskip` to flush align the lines at the bottom.

Move the `\leading{16pt}` before the `\checkandfixlayout` command and you will get perfectly aligned pages. Setting the `\parskip` to 0pt is not a sensible solution, it will only lead to lots of warnings like this:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Btw: In a high quality book you should never use `\sloppy` globally. That should be only a last resort for problematic paragraphs.